# AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier failed

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Something wrong while try to acquire Token.
`ERROR [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication: [Correlation ID: ] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier failed. java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.Collections$SingletonList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.util.URLUtils.serializeParameters(URLUtils.java:103) ~[oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.64.4.jar:5.64.4] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createOauthHttpRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:57) ~[__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:35) ~[__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:128) ~[__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:63) ~[__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.acquireTokenByClientCredential(AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.java:63) ~[__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.java:49) ~[__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:69) [__app__.jar:?] at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:18) [__app__.jar:?] at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) [?:?]`

Answer (score 0):

This error does not seem to have anything in common with Azure Data Explorer or its SDK. There is not a single ADX SDK-related line in this stack trace.?
I would recommend reading documentation on MSAL.java